# Creating a Python list with given indexes for each repeating element

Tags: python, arrays, list

First list : contains the **list indexes of corresponding category name**

Second list : contains the **category names**  as string

```
Intervals=[[Indexes_Cat1],[Indexes_Cat2],[Indexes_Cat3], ...]

Category_Names=["cat1","cat2","cat3",...]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
list=["cat1", "cat1","cat2","cat3","cat3"]
```

where indexes of any element in output list is placed using Intervals list.

**Ex1:**

```
Intervals=[[0,4], [2,3] , [1,5]]
Category_Names=["a","b","c"]
```

**Ex: Output1**

```
["a","c","b","b","a","c"]
```

**Edit: More Run Cases**

**Ex2:**

```
Intervals=[[0,1], [2,3] , [4,5]]
Category_Names=["a","b","c"]
```

**Ex: Output2**

```
["a","a","b","b","c","c"]
```

**Ex3:**

```
Intervals=[[3,4], [1,5] , [0,2]]
Category_Names=["a","b","c"]
```

**Ex: Output3**

```
["c","b","c","a","a","b"]
```

**My solution:**

Create any empty array of size n.

Run a for loop for each category.

```
output=[""]*n
for i in range(len(Category_Names)):
    for index in Intervals[I]:
       output[index]=Categories[i]
```

Is there a better solution, or a more pythonic way? Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example that others can actually run please?

Comment: @Paddy3118 I added 2 more cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def categorise(Intervals=[[0,4], [2,3] , [1,5]],
               Category_Names=["a","b","c"]):
    flattened = sum(Intervals, [])
    answer = [None] * (max(flattened) + 1)
    for indices, name in zip(Intervals, Category_Names):
        for i in indices:
            answer[i] = name
    return answer

assert categorise() == ['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c']
assert categorise([[3,4], [1,5] , [0,2]], 
                  ["a","b","c"]) == ['c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
```

Note that in this code you will get `None` values in the answer if the "intervals" don't cover all integers from zero to the max interval number. It is assumed that the input is compatable.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a way to avoid the nested loop (I can't think of any right now) so it seems your solution is good.

A way you could do it a bit better is to construct the output array with one of the categories:

```
output = [Category_Names[0]]*n
```

and then start the iteration skipping that category:

```
for i in range(1, len(Category_Names)):
```

If you know there is a category that appears more than the others then you should use that as the one initializing the array.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I actually thought your solution but couldn't make sure creating an empty array or with default values runs faster. Thanks ,Appreciated

Comment: Well, in your solution you were already creating the n-size array but with empty strings (`output=[""]*n`) so using one of the categories saves some time as you don't need to rewrite those ones. I am glad that my answer was helpful.

Comment: BTW does the `n` come as an input or do you need to calculate it?

Comment: @jpmontoya n is known, it is known (a O(1) look up). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of strings created and use `enumerate` to avoid `range(len(..))` for indexing.

```
Intervals=[[0,4], [2,3] , [1,5]]
Category_Names=["a","b","c"]

n = max(x for a in Intervals for x in a) + 1

# do not construct strings that get replaced anyhow    
output=[None] * n

for i,name in enumerate(Category_Names):
    for index in Intervals[i]:
       output[index]=name

print(output)
```

Output:

```
["a","c","b","b","a","c"]
```